# Firebase Hosting not running Sveltekit

Tags: firebase, svelte, sveltekit

I've created an app using Sveltekit and I want to host it statically on Firebase.

My svelte.config.js file is as follows:

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            pages: 'public',
            assets: 'public',
            fallback: 'index.html',
            precompress: false
        }),
        prerender: {
            default: true
        }
    },
    preprocess: [
        preprocess({
            postcss: true
        })
    ]
};

export default config;
```

My firebase.json is like this:

```js
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [ {
      "source": "**",
      "destination": "/index.html"
    } ]
  }
}
```

When I visit the site using the firebase provided URL, only the HTML is rendered in my browsers, and no CSS or Javascript is executed. I see that all of the files are served to my browser, they just do not run. I have no issues in development and when previewing, only when deploying. Any idea on what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Which SvelteKit version is this? In the current there's this error when building ` config.kit.prerender.default has been removed. You can set it inside the top level +layout.js instead` (I just tried to build and deploy a new project of the current version `next.465` and your config without the `prerender` and `preprocess` which worked fine)

Comment: I'm on version `@sveltejs/kit@1.0.0-next.442`. I'm not sure if the error existed in this version, but it has gotten very annoying. I tried to switch to Vercel and face the same issue. I need the preprocess since I am using Tailwind CSS for styling. Any Idea on what I can do?

Comment: Update: updated to the newest version of svetekit and still facing the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing this question for now. Seems to have been a bug with the version of Sveltekit I was using.

Comment: So it's now working with what version? Did you have to change the config or do something else? That might be useful information to provide for someone else finding the question...

Comment: I would have loved to provide a clean solution to my problem. However, to fix my issue, I created a new project using the latest version of Sveltekit `next.465` and just copied over my src files. The only change I made to the base `svelte.config.js` was to add preprocess.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?
https://www.npmjs.com/package/svelte-adapter-firebase

I did not search for but maybe there is a "static" configuration.

Comment: I have tried this, doesn't work unfortunately with the version of sveltekit I am using.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).